# Pytmx loads no tiles or textures, it seems

Tags: textures, tilemap, python, pygame

So, I've been trying to load a tmx file through pytmx But when it loads the file, it only loads a black image with the same resolution as the tmx file.

```python
class TiledMap:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        file = load_pygame(filename,pixelalpha=True)
        self.width = file.width*file.tilewidth
        self.height = file.height*file.tileheight
        self.filedata = file
    def render(self,surface):
        tImage = self.filedata.get_tile_image_by_gid
        for layer in self.filedata.visible_layers:
            if isinstance(layer,pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x,y,gid, in layer:
                    tile = tImage(gid)
                    if tile:
                        surface.fill(pygame.Color(0,0,0,0))
                        surface.blit(tile,(x*self.filedata.tilewidth,y*self.filedata.tileheight))
    def make_map(self):
        temp_surface = pygame.Surface((self.width,self.height))
        self.render(temp_surface)
        return temp_surface

class Camera:
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(0,0,width,height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        print("True")
    def apply(self,entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)
    def apply_rect(self,rect):
        return rect.move(self.camera.topleft)
    def update(self,target):
        x = -target.rect.centerx + int(WIDTH/2)
        y = -target.rect.centery + int(HEIGHT/2)
        x = min(0,x)
        y = min(0,y)
        x = max(-(self.width-WIDTH),x)
        y = max(-(self.height-HEIGHT),y)
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(x,y,self,width,self.height)

class Gm():
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.rungame = True

class Platform1(Gm):
    def __init__(self,game):
        Gm.__init__(self,game)
        self.player = pygame.image.load(r"textures\player\stand.png")
        self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player,(150,150)).convert_alpha()
        self.mask1 = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.player)
        gameFolder = path.dirname(__file__)
        mapFolder = path.join(gameFolder,"lvl")
        self.map = TiledMap(path.join(mapFolder,"level1.tmx"))
        self.camera = Camera(self.map.width, self.map.height)
        self.map_img = self.map.make_map()
        self.map_rect = self.map_img.get_rect()
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 700
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10


        while self.rungame:
            self.game.clock.tick(60)
            self.game.screen.blit(self.player,(self.x,self.y))
            self.game.screen.blit(self.map_img,self.camera.apply_rect(self.map_rect))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    self.playing = False
                    self.rungame = False
                    exit(0)
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                            pygame.quit()
                            self.playing = False
                            self.rungame = False
                            exit(0)
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[pygame.K_d]:
                self.x += 5
            if key[pygame.K_a]:
                self.x -= 5
            if not (self.isJump):
                if key[pygame.K_w]:
                    self.isJump = True
            else:
                if self.jumpCount >= -10:
                    neg = 1
                    if self.jumpCount < 0:
                        neg = -1
                    self.y -= (self.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
                    self.jumpCount -= 1
                else:
                    self.isJump = False
                    self.jumpCount = 10
            pygame.display.flip()

            self.game.screen.fill((0,0,255))
```

Yeah.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. When you created the tile set in Tiled, did you happen to check the box for `use transparency color`?

Comment: I had no such option.